# is it possible to design view for iPad without autolayout?

Tags: ios, ipad, xib

I have developed app without autolayout for iPhone. Now I need that app for iPad also. Is it possible to create it without autolayout?

Comment: Yes you can do in to iPad without use of auto layout but it's not a good practice.

Comment: Why you want to avoid autolayout for iPad?

Comment: you'll need to create a seprate nib or storyboard

Answer (score 2):

yes, you have to create App directly then select iPad.
and using Auto Resize ,you can directly develop app for iPad only.

I have attached few Screen shot, may be helpful to you.

Create new project, using XIB .

[image: Select iPad new Project]

[image: Select iPad for new File]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Nilesh, you have to remove Auto layout , and then set Auto resize

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend that (see comment of @Nimit Parekh).

You can use `Sized classes` to avoid having 2 separate `Storyboards` - one for `iPhone` and other for `iPad`. There is a [good tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial).

Second option is to have 2 `storyboards`. You only need to link all outlets from the 1st storyboard to the second. You have to check not to miss something, otherwise you can get exceptions in `iPad`.

The 3rd option is manually (from the code) to manage layout for iPad - but this will create a lot of specific code for iPad only (you have to check what type is your device and split code) - this is not recommended.

Take into account that `Autolayout` is more easy to apply on `iPad` (from my point of view) because of equal withd / height ratio for iPad - it is the same up to now. Not like in iPhone.