# iPad Application disable Autlolayout Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, swift3

I am creating a ipad application , so I dont want to use Auto Layout Constraints. I searched a lot and got that I have to disable Autolayout and enable Size classes. [This Link I reffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046612/is-it-possible-to-design-view-for-ipad-without-autolayout) . But I am not getting this option in my project.  Please help me how to do this.

As perthe comment I disabled autolayout. But I am still not getting it in a proper way. Here is the screenshots

[image: storyBoard Image]

[image: simulater and View Controller Image]

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: Size classes are part of auto layout; they allow you to specify different constraints and constraint values for different traits.  If you disable auto layout then you must also disable size classes.  Why don't you want to use autolayout?  The fact that you are creating an iPad app should be nothing to do with using auto layout or not, but the old springs and struts approach is far inferior to constraints and autolayout

Comment: Yes I am using Story Board.

Comment: Actually the application I am working is not using AutoLayout and its working fine in ipad. I have to create a similar application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like , select your current View Controller , and go  to `File Inspector` in Xcode, and **uncheck** the `Use AutoLayout` and **uncheck** the `Use Trait variations`

[image]

Comment: No.. still am not getting it properly.. I have taken a label in center. And my scrren size is ipad pro 9.7. But when I am running it in ipad pro 12.9 , its coming in little left

Comment: set your margin in center , not left in autoresizing